Does the existence of derivatives in the average sense imply absolute continuity?
Let $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be a measurable function. Suppose there exists some integrable function $g$, and a measurable set $E$ of full measure such that
$$\lim_{r \to 0_+} \sup_{x \in E} \left | \frac{1}{r^2} \int_0^r f(x+t) - f(x-t)  \, dt - g(x) \right | = 0.$$
Question: Does $f$ admit an absolutely continuous representative with derivative $g$? That is, an absolutely continuous function $\tilde f$ with $\tilde f = f$ a.e., and $\tilde f’ = g$ a.e.
Comments:

A quite remarkable consequence of the above would be the following characterisation of (equivalence classes of) continuously differentiable functions.


Theorem (?): A function $f$ admits a continuously differentiable representative if and only if it satisfies the hypotheses of the original claim and further $g$ is continuous.


The desired result is closely related to the result proven in the post Uniformly Lebesgue differentiable functions.


Seven edits within one hour after posting the question?

@Jochen Wengenroth Sorry about that, was trying to edit the question to make the motivation more clear.

I believe it is not true but fails in a very delicate way. Have you calculate the sup over $r$ when $f(x)=x\log|x|-x$ or $f(x)=x\log|\log|x||$?

@LidingYao I guess you mean the sup over $x$? I think in the case of these functions, the singularity at $0$ in the derivative could rule out uniform convergence over $E$. But I’m not sure…

My guess is to consider some infinite sum where each term is translation and scaling of such $f$.

@LidingYao: But $f(x)=x\log |x|$ is absolutely continuous.

Shouldn't we at least assume $f$ to be locally integrable, or else what is meant by the integrals?

@ChristianRemling Indeed, my bad.

Let $F(x)=\int_0^x f(t)\, dt$. Then our assumption says that
$$
G_r(x)\equiv \frac{F(x+r)+F(x-r)-2F(x)}{r^2} \to g(x)
$$
as $r\to 0+$, uniformly on $E$. Thus also $G_r\to g$ in $\mathcal D'$ (= as distributions), by dominated convergence. However, in $\mathcal D'$, these difference quotients are just another way to obtain the distributional derivatives; this is well known in the simpler version for the first distributional derivative $u'$ of a $u\in\mathcal D'$, which we can obtain as $u'=\lim (\tau_h u-u)/h$, with the limit taken in $\mathcal D'$, but the argument is the same here: the operations are moved over to the test functions $\varphi$, and for these we have the required convergence to $\varphi''$ in the topology of $\mathcal D$.
We conclude that $F''=g$ in $\mathcal D'$, but $F'=f$, so we see that $f$ has an integrable distributional derivative and thus is absolutely continuous.

I think the u' is u-tau_hu, there is a negative sign.

@LidingYao: Well, I didn't say what exactly I mean by $\tau_h$ and if this is $u(x+h)$ when $u$ is a function, then my formula looks fine.

Yes that's fine. I guess usual notation is $\tau_hf(x)=f(x-h)$.
